# Why isn't there a space in the middle of my pyramid?

Tags: c, cs50

So I am trying to solve https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/psets/1/mario/more/ this problem set from cs50.

It's taken me way too long to get this far (5-6 hours WITH help from youtube).

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_positive_int(void);
int main(void)
{
    int n = get_positive_int();
    // Run a below loop until i is greater than n
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      // Run if statement on the same row until j is greater than n*2 + i+1
        for(int j=0; j < n*2 + i+1; j++)
        {
            // Create a blank space in exact center of the pyramid
            if(j + i - n == 0 || j + i - n == 1)
                printf(" ");
            //If the value of n-1 is less than the combined value of j and i, or 
            //if the value of i and n minus j is less than or equal to zero print #
            else if ( j + i > n - 1 || i + n - j <= 0)
                printf("#");
            else 
                //otherwise print " "
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the below create a two " " in the center of my pyramid?

```
if(j + i - n == 0 || j + i - n == 1)
                printf(" ");
```

And why when I choose a value of 1 for n does the program not print anything?

What is this specific type of thinking/math called? I am having difficulty grasping it and I am not sure how to find information online because I don't know what it is called.

My output is below.
When N = 8

```
          #######
         #########
        ###########
       #############
      ###############
     #################
    ###################
   #####################
```

The output I want is.
When N = 8

```
       #  #
      ##  ##
     ###  ###
    ####  ####
   #####  #####
  ######  ######
 #######  #######
########  ########
```

When I input a value of 1 I get.

What I want when I input 1 is,

```
#  #
```

I'd like to know what specifically I did wrong in order to fix the issue myself, rather than the direct answer if possible.

Comment: Show what the output is and what output you want instead

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger? Usually, when the internal state or output of a program behind to deviate from the expected is extremely revealing. If you can trace through the steps it's doing vs what you think you told it to do, you will figure out how to fix it.

Comment: The middle spaces are always at the same position regardless of the row, so the condition for writing them should depend on `j` and not on `i`.

Comment: Try `if(j + i - n == 0 || j + i - n == 1) printf("%d", j + i - n);` ... of course that will mess up your triangle, but maybe give you an idea what you need to change

Comment: @Multiplify - What you also did wrong in my opinion: All comments but the third are nothing more than transcriptions of the respective statement and as such have no added value.

Comment: You should perhaps have solved the problem in steps: 1. Print the correct number of leading spaces. 2. Print the left hand bricks. 3. Print the gap. 4. Print the right hand bricks. 4. Ready - no spaces to the right are required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all observe that your two `for` loops both start from `0`. Thus at the beginning both `i` and `j` are equal to `0`. Therefore, since `n` is a positive integer, both your `if` and `else if` clauses are evaluated as `false` and only the final `else` gets executed, which is `printf(" ");`

Now look at your pyramid. Your "pyramid" fills a space with `n` rows and `2*n + 2` columns. The first loop `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)` is for the rows, and it's correct, since there are `n` rows. Your second `for` loop, however, is faulty. It should be `for (int j=0; j < n*2 + 2; j++)`.

Now when we look at the the i-th row we see that (remembering rows start from `0` because we started counting `i` from `0`), you want to print n-1-i spaces, followed by i+1 `#` characters followed by 2 spaces, followed by i+1 `#` characters and finally followed by n-1-i spaces. So the "spaces" are when `j < n-1-i` (remember `j` also starts from `0`), when `j == n` and `j == n+1` and when `j > n+2+i`

This can be written as follows using `if-else`:

```
if ( j < (n-1-i) || j == n || j == n+1 || j > n+2+i) printf(" ");
else printf("#");
```

So the final code will look like:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_positive_int(void);

int main(void)
{
    int n = get_positive_int();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < n*2 + 2; j++)
        {
            if ( j < (n-1-i) || j == n || j == n+1 || j > n+2+i) printf(" ");
            else printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: He said he has already spent 5-6 hours on this. I've pointed out the error in the `for` loop and explained how to approach constructing the `if-else` statement. It's not like I just gave him the solution and didn't explain anything.

Comment: Yes, I like your explanation (upvoted) and removed my impulsive comment, sorry.

Comment: I'm working my way through it right now and I appreciate your response as well as everybody else. What is this kind of problem called and where can I find more practice problems of a similar nature so I can understand it better?

Comment: @Multiplify you can construct your own. Try to make upside down triangles, right triangles, diamonds (grows until n-th row then shrinks), crosses, even christmas trees, ball-shapes etc. These are usually good exercises for getting comfortable with nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

Think about this mathematically. You have slope of `-1`, so we have `j = -i + k`. Our formula becomes `k = i + j`. If we have `n = 5`:

```
i j k
0 4 4
1 3 4
2 2 4
3 1 4
5 0 4
```

`n = 6`

```
i j k
0 5 5
1 4 5
2 3 5
3 2 5
4 1 5
5 0 5
```

so `k = n - 1`

That is first half, second is even easier, `j = i + k`, so `k = j - i`. It is positive slope moved by `k`. So for `n=5`

```
i j k
0 4 4
1 5 4
2 6 4
3 7 4
5 8 4
```

`n = 6`

```
i j k
0 5 5
1 6 5
2 7 5
3 8 5
4 9 5
5 10 5
```

look at that we have a match in both cases `k = n - 1`. So our formulas are
`j = -i + n - 1` and `j = i + n - 1`.

Second in both cases we have maximum `j` at `max(i) + k` or in other words `n - 1 + n - 1` so `2 * n - 2`

so:

1. We got your lines.
2. Look closes and you will see how far your `j` has to go.

Here is the code:

```
// int get_positive_int(void);
int main(void)
{
    int n = 5; //get_positive_int();
    // Run a below loop until i is greater than n
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        // Run if statement on the same row until j is greater than n*2 + i+1
        for(int j = 0; j < n * 2 - 1; j++)
        {                                                                                                                                                     
            // Create a blank space in exact center of the pyramid
            if (j == n - i - 1 || j == n + i - 1)
                printf("#");
            else 
                //otherwise print " "
                printf(".");
        }   
        printf("\n");
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
....#....
...#.#...
..#...#..
.#.....#.
#.......#
```

Now you can optimize this to trim down number of inner loop execution by `25%`, by looking at this. I do not need to go beyond the point where I print my second `#`, meaning beyond `max(j) = j + 1` value of my second formula `+ 1` is because I still want to be able to go into loop, so we get maximum `max(j) = (n + i - 1) + 1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// int get_positive_int(void);
int main(void)
{
    int n = 5; //get_positive_int();
    // Run a below loop until i is greater than n
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // Run if statement on the same row until j is greater than n*2 + i+1
        for(int j = 0; j < n + i; j++)                                                                                                                        
        {
            // Create a blank space in exact center of the pyramid
            if (j == n - i - 1 || j == n + i - 1)
                printf("#");
            else
                //otherwise print " "
                printf(".");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

output:

```
....#
...#.#
..#...#
.#.....#
#.......#
```

And if you notice, by thinking mathematically about this you save a lot of operations. For example in second `for()` loop, OP and other answer have more than 1 operations, where this has 1, in `if/else` both have more than 2 equality statements having, this one has 2.

NOTE: I used `.` instead of   for demonstration.

Comment: I think I follow. This is all super new to me, I am only three days in. But one of our main differences is that I don't want the interior of my triangle to be hollow, and I need a space of two lines between the two halves. I will keep digesting this though. Thanks for the input!